# Is there any documention about ELF file's version sections?

Tags: elf

I see an Elf file may contains version sections like .gnu.version (readelf -V to display thire contents). What is the meaning of these information? Is there any documentation about version sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the most complete piece of documentation is [Ulrich Drepper's notes](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/symbol-versioning) however stale/incomplete they are. You can also get some inspiration from [Solaris docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-1984/chapter5-84101/index.html) (Linux dynamic linking is a shameles^W copy of Solaris after all).

Many people have complained about lack of definitive documentation including [Glibc maintainers themselves](https://cygwin.com/ml/libc-help/2016-10/msg00008.html).

Comment: This helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the GLIBC and the Solaris implementations are quite different :( I worked under the assumptions they were similar before, and turns out they are not at all.

Comment: Yep, that's why I used the word "inspiration" :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to yugr's more implementation documentation, I have [blogged about this](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/tags/versioning/) a few times in the past, so you can look there for some "why and how to use" information.

Comment: Thanks Diego. Just wanted to say that your blog is always an interesting and in-depth read. Keep on!